# Why d3.transition() has no effect where theUpdateSelection.transition() works?

Tags: d3.js, transition

Complete fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/scottbrown0001/o7qL4dpr/

I'm emulating what I see in the source of https://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/, and I'm getting a bit of different behavior I don't understand.

Mike Bostock's source lines 142 &ff and 171 &ff has

```
var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(top, function(d) { return d.State; });

// ...snippage...

var barUpdate = d3.transition(bar)
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0," + (d.y0 = y(d.State)) + ")"; })
  .style("fill-opacity", 1);
```

and my corresponding lines 44 &ff and 78 &ff of the fiddle has

```
var circGraphic = playground.selectAll(".circ-g")
  .data(CIRCLES, function(d) {
    return d.name;
  });

// ...snippage...

var circUpdate = d3.transition(circGraphic)
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    console.log("UPDATING to " + circ_y(circIndex(step + i)));
    return "translate(" + circ_x(i) + "," + circ_y(circIndex(step + i)) + ")";
    });
```

which, given the way `bar` and `circGraphic` are defined, sure look parallel. But in my case there's no visible change to the graphic.

If I change line 78 so that I have

```
circGraphic.transition()
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    console.log("UPDATING to " + circ_y(circIndex(step + i)));
    return "translate(" + circ_x(i) + "," + circ_y(circIndex(step + i)) + ")";
    });
```

(switch the commenting out of lines 77 & 78 in the fiddle) the graphic works as expected.

I've been poring over the example and the documentation and playing with my code and I can't figure out why this difference. Anyone see anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the reason: you're using **D3 version 4.x**, while Bostock's example uses <s>**D3 version 3.x**</s> (actually, version 2.x).

Those versions have different `transition()` functions, regarding the arguments. In D3 v3.x, this is the function:

```
d3.transition([selection], [name])
```

Meaning that the first argument is the selection. But in D3 v4.x:

```
selection.transition([name])
```

Meaning that the only argument it takes is the name of the transition, not the selection.

Also, mind the fact that, this being version 4.x, you may have to `merge()` the selections.

Comment: Thanks for the link, your explanation of the use of merge and 3.x/4.x makes imminent sense and is the exact thing I was searching and searching for in the docs yesterday!

I saw something to the following effect (for 3.0) but couldn't find it again when I realized I needed it. Is the following summary correctly stated?

- In d3 3.x, the enter() selection includes the update() selection.
- In d3 4.x, the update() selection and enter() selection are separate and until merged modifications to the update() selection will not affect the enter() selection elements.

Answer (score 1):

Your code would work fine if you were using d3 v3. You are using v4 and the method you are trying to use is no longer available.

Here is your code using d3 v3 : https://jsfiddle.net/kopov76u/ (all I had to change was the way you declare the `scaleOrdinal(...)` which also has changed in v4. The rest is the same and your transition works fine with both methods.)

[This](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Transitions.md#d3_transition) is the method you're using when using `d3.transition(circGraphic)`. As he mentions in the docs

> This method is used rarely, as it is typically easier to derive a transition from an existing selection, rather than deriving a selection from an existing transition

which refers to the "other" method you use : `circGraphic.transition().attr(...)`

You'll probably find that most examples, even the ones for d3 v3 use the latter method.

All that to say, there was nothing wrong with your interpretation of mbostock's example per se, just the wrong version of the lib.

Comment: Thank you! I did see the comment you included, but then saw the example using it so I was unsure. Your answer and Gerardo's make a tough choice in terms of which to accept!